# Fazer uma section como o exemplo

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando fazer uma section como a da imagem abaixo, mas estou com alguns problemas para posicionar os círculos da maneira que preciso.

[image: Como é pra ficar]

Na parte verde é para ter um texto e o box dela deve sobrepor o header (imagem que está acima), fiz ele colocando uma margin-top negativa, não sei se essa é a melhor maneira, mas a minha dificuldade está em fazer a section ao lado, com os 6 círculos.

```
<section>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
      <div class="row">AQUI ENTRA 3 CIRCULOS E UM TEXTO ABAIXO DELES</div>
      <div class="row">AQUI ENTRA 3 E UM TEXTO ABAIXO DELES/div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 box-green">
        <h2 class="display-3">Texto da parte verde.</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Fiz os circulos, porém não sei como posso botar um texto dentro deles e um icone dentro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que usar as [classes flex do Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) como `d-flex`, `flex-wrap`, `justify-content-around`, e outra como `w-100` e `text-center` para ajustar tudo e `border border-danger` e `rounded-circle` para fazer a bola, basicamente tirando o CSS da altura e largura do circulo vc não precisa de mais nada...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<section>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="border border-danger rounded-circle box mx-auto">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="border border-danger rounded-circle box mx-auto">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="border border-danger rounded-circle box mx-auto">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <p class="text-center">texto</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <p class="text-center">texto</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <p class="text-center">texto</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="border border-danger rounded-circle box mx-auto">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="border border-danger rounded-circle box mx-auto">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <div class="border border-danger rounded-circle box mx-auto">1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <p class="text-center">texto</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <p class="text-center">texto</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4">
                  <p class="text-center">texto</p>
              </div>
          </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-1 box-green">
              <h2 class="display-3">Texto da parte verde.</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Acho que não me fiz entender bem, seria um palavra embaixo de cada circulo. Mas muito obrigado de qualquer maneira, ajudou bastante.

Comment: @GuilhermeRigotti agora entendi melhor fiz uma revisão do código agora ficou como vc precisava. Tive que dividir o grid e col-4 para vc ter 3 colunas iguais encima e embaixo, com a bola e o texto.